# n-th crossing with event detection in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: python, events, scipy, ode

I would like to know if there is any way to stop the ODE integration after a specific number of detected events. I know that scipy.integrate.solve_ivp allows making an event terminate or not, but I want to know if it’s possible to make it terminate at the n-th event, where n is a integer number bigger than one.

For example, is it possible to compute only the first three interactions with an event and then stop the integration? If this is not possible, is there an alternative library to do it?

I read the official documentation of scipy related with the integration of ODE but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Slight generalization of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63453965/scipy-solve-ivp-terminate-trajectory-on-second-occurrence-of-event, and related  to https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14176. There is not a built-in feature in SciPy; just hacks.

Comment: @MattHaberland Since the solver is looking for a zero-crossing, one might be able to write the event function such that it keeps track of the sign changes and returns fake values until a certain number of crosses have been detected (at which point the ode solver would root find the last event for termination).

Comment: Right; that would be an aforementioned "hack" : ) It so happens I tried a few similar things already, but not exactly that - depends on whether the solver calls `event` in unexpected ways. If I find that this works, I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example hack. As suggested in the comments, `wrapped_event` returns an arbitrary value before the required number of events has been reached, then it starts returning the true event function. (There is a little extra complexity due to sign issues when detecting event crossings.) All you should need to do to use it with your own code is to wrap your event function with `wrap_event`, that pass the result into `solve_ivp`. Respecting the `terminal` attribute of the event is not requested, but easy to accommodate.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

def wrap_event(event, n_events, t0, y0):
    def wrapped_event(t, y, n_events=n_events):
        new_event = event(t, y)
        if wrapped_event.count < n_events:
            new_sign = np.sign(new_event)
            if new_sign == -wrapped_event.sign:
                wrapped_event.count += 1
                wrapped_event.sign = new_sign
            return -1
        return new_event * (-1)**(n_events)
    wrapped_event.count = 1
    wrapped_event.sign = np.sign(event(t0, y0))
    wrapped_event.terminal = event.terminal
    return wrapped_event

def f(t, y):
    return [y[1], -y[0]]

def event(t, y):
    return y[0]
event.terminal = True

t0 = 0
tf = 100
y0 = [1, 0]
n_events = 3

sol = integrate.solve_ivp(f, (t0, tf), y0, dense_output=True, 
                          events=wrap_event(event, n_events, t0, y0))
t = np.linspace(sol.t[0], sol.t[-1], 300)
x = sol.sol(t)
plt.plot(t, x[0])
```

[image]